# Drupal Views: Get nodes with the same taxonomy as the current node

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I have a Content-Type with taxonomy-terms. It's a select-list, so it can have only one taxonomy - at least of that vocabulary. Now I need to build a view that lists all nodes with the same taxonomy.

Thought that this wouldn't be too hard since it sounds pretty basic. Yet I can't get it working. Any ideas? I'm trying to avoid writing a module for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer works in Views version 2 or higher. First you need to install Views attach ( http://drupal.org/project/views_attach ). Please read about Views attach before proceeding further. Views attach is best explained by this video http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37

Now we get to Views attach. Please enable the views attach module before proceeding. Essentially `Views attach` attaches a view at the end of the node. In our case our view will be a listing of other articles with the same term.

We will essentially need to "pass" the taxonomy term of the node to the view. Let the name of your Vocabulary be called `MyVocab`.

Steps to make the view.

1. Lets call the view `display_other_articles_with_same_taxonomy`.
2. Add a display of type `Node Content` (available after enabling Views attach). This is a display just like block and page displays but with special ability of attaching itself to the node.

Make the following settings in the `Node Content Display`

```
Node content settings
Node types: [select the content types you are interested in seeing the list of nodes with same taxonomy term]
Build modes: Teaser, Full node
Arguments: token
Show title: No
```

You should select `Use tokens from the node the view is attached to` under Arguments. Let the token be `[term-id]` This is the **"ID of top taxonomy term"**. This is very important!! Essentially you are going to be passing the taxonomy term of the node from the `MyVocab` (See http://groups.drupal.org/node/11788#comment-38332). If it has the lowest weight, the taxonomy vocabulary will be the first vocabulary in the taxonomy section of your node edit form. Add an argument `Taxonomy: Term Id`.

Add the fields you are interested in e.g. `Node: Title`. Make sure the `Node: Title` is made into a hyperlink by ticking `Link this field to its Node`

So what this view is going to do is:

1. Take the taxonomy term from the `MyVocab` vocabulary in the Node that is currently being viewed
2. Pass that as argument to the view `display_other_articles_with_same_taxonomy`
3. List all the nodes that have the same taxonomy term as the node being displayed.

Thats it!

If you're using Views 3 (currently at alpha3 at the time of writing) *and* you want a block (right now the articles have same taxonomy term come at the end of node body) you can do it in the following fashion:

1. Forget about views attach... its not required
2. Add a block view. It should contain the same argument, fields and filters as the instructions above for the `Node Content` display.
3. You need to modify the settings for the argument `Taxononomy: Term Id` just slightly: Under `Action to take if argument is not present:` choose `[x] Provide Default Argument`. Choose `[x] Taxonomy Term ID from URL`. Now make sure `[] Load default argument from term page` is unselected and `[x] Load default argument from node page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks.` Also `[x]Limit terms by vocabulary` and choose the `Series` vocabulary.
4. Make sure you name the block and put it in the appropriate region.

**Note:** This answer is subset of the answer I provided at [How to just show NodeQueue block on included nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895213/how-to-just-show-nodequeue-block-on-included-nodes/3909670#3909670) In that scenario the requirement was that the related articles are explicitly selected and listed in a particular order. Its a little more complex and uses Nodequeues which we don't need here at all.

Answer (score 10):

While this was technically possible with Views 2 as described in some of the other answers, Views 3 has this integration built in.

You can create an argument for the taxonomy term id and then choose *"Provide default argument"*. This will then give you an option for *"Taxonomy Term ID from URL"* and *"Load default argument from node page..."*

This will allow you to take the taxonomy of a page and pass that as an argument to your view block.

Note: Views 3 is currently in Alpha 3 but in my experience is at a relatively stable state and I am using it on production sites. If it has features like the one above that you find useful please use it, test it and submit bugs/patches if you encounter any issues!

Comment: -1: Views 3 is not in stable release.  Drupal modules have a tendency to be very buggy until stable, even in beta.  This is not to discredit anything the views team has done, but overall it's just best practice to use stable software.

Comment: While you are correct that Views 3 has not yet moved to a final release, Views 3 is listed as "supported." The way Drupal modules get tested and moved from dev channel, to alpha, to beta, to an official release is by having the community use them, test them, and report any issues that they might encounter. I don't feel that my answer is any less valid of a response to the question as long as it is clear what you are getting/giving up by choosing Views 3 as opposed to Views 2, which the Views project page does quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Use relationships

1. Node 1 -> Relationship 1 -> Term  // This will be relationships->taxonomy->term
2. Term -> Relationship 2 -> Node 2 // This will be relationships->node->node
3. Argument NID to filter NODE 1
4. Fields or node full view on Relationship 2 (you will see select box on field adding form, to determinate what NODE to use)

Comment: This looks like it could be the best solution, but it is so terse that I can't follow it. A little more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Views gives you the options to add filters.  Click the plus sign in the filters area of the views admin UI, select Taxonomy from the list, check either Term or ID, and fill in the value that you need to filter by.

EDIT (for explicit instructions):

1. First, add the necessary fields that you want under the fields section that you want to display from the nodes that you are trying to filter such as node title, etc.
2. Under Arguments, click the plus sign and select Taxonomy
3. Check Taxonomy: Term and click Add
4. Click Update

In your preview area test it out by adding an argument and clicking preview.  If it doesn't work, your nodes do not have attached taxonomy, your views module is corrupted, or you didn't follow directions.

Comment: Well, i don't want to build a block for every term that i have. I thought of using arguments somewhere.

Comment: Then add an argument - views lets you do this as well.  Just follow the same procedure.  And you wouldn't have to build a block - it can be put into a page or whatever.

Comment: Well obviously i tried, but i can't get it working. I tried using relationships as well… could you give some more detailed explanation?